# How to display components with a delay in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have the following which is intended to indicate to the user that the app is loading:

```
function LoadingIndicatorView() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator color='#009b88' size='large' />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

After 5 seconds pass, I want `"Please wait..."` to show up underneath the `ActivityIndicator`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

you can try following this:

```
function LoadingIndicatorView() {
    const [isLoading , seIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

    React.useEffect(()=>{
       const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
         seIsLoading (false);
       }, 5000);

       return () => { 
         clearTimeout(timeout);
       };
    },[]);

    return isLoading ? ( null ) : (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator color='#009b88' size='large' />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

You can put instead of **null** every thing you want.

Comment: My function was not to determine *if* the app is loading, I already made sure that everything in the return statement of my function means the app is loading. I just want "Please wait..." to show up after 5 seconds